# Get First Commit with SVN Hook

Tags: svn, repository, svn-hooks

HI... Im trying to make a svn hook to check the first commit in repository. SVN Hook dont support "Add". So if i get the first commit, i can simulate the first entery of file in repository.
I dont have any ideias, please help.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are in the pre-commit hook. You can use [svnlook command](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn-book.html#svn.ref.svnlook) like the following

```
svnlook changed -t TXN REPOS_PATH
```

to get the information about files/folders which have been added etc. Furthermore you can check by

```
svnlook youngest REPOS_PATH
```

which revision does the repository have at the moment so the combination of the **svnlook youngest** and the above **svnlook changed** should solve your problem.